# Using forall for a set in a Tuple

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to do something like below. I want to get the sum of the continuous variable Xbdt for all BlockBelow corresponding to Pbd.pitblockSet :

```
forall(i in Pbd.pitblockSet , d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods ) {
 sum(j in BlockBelow[i] ) Xbdt[j.id][d][t] == 0;
}
```

Seems I am not writing the Pbd.pitblockSet correctly. Any suggestions on how to write this ?

I get some errors :
Cannot use the type {blockType}[Pbd] with "in"
Cannot use type  as index in {blockType}.
Expecting a tuple type, found {Path}.

Where Pbd is a tuple of type Path and is read from excel data

```
tuple Path {
int id;
string source;
string dest;
{string} pitblockSet;
{string} roadPoints; 
{string} dumpblockSet;
{string} others;
float dist;
};

{Path} Pbd={}; // set of paths from block b to dump d
```

DumpBlocks and PitBlocks are read from excel and are of type {String}

BlockBelow is calculated as below :

```
tuple blockType {
    key string id;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
 };

{blockType} PitBlocksType = ...; //read from excel

//find one block below each block
{blockType} BlockBelow[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
     {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == b.i -1 &&
                        (b1.k  == b.k ) &&
                         (b1.j  == b.j) };
```

Xbdt is a decision variable

```
dvar float+ Xbdt[PitBlocks][DumpBlocks][TimePeriods];
```

-------------- ADDED AFTER ANSWER -----------------------

Thank you for the answer Daniel, I have tried the following :

```
forall (p in Pbd) {
  forall(i in p.pitblockSet , d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods ) {
    sum(j in BlockBelow[i] ) Xbdt[j.id][d][t] == 0;
  }
}
```

I get an error Cannot use type string for

I then tried :

```
forall (p in Pbd) {
  forall(i in PitBlocksInPathD[p] , d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods ) {
    sum(j in BlockBelow[i] ) Xbdt[j.id][d][t] == 0;
  }
}
```

Which seems to have worked. I had created the PitBlocksInPathD as below :

```
{blockType} PitBlocksInPathD[p in Pbd] = union(b in p.pitblockSet) {b2 | b2 in PitBlocksType : b2.id == b};
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is `Pdb.pitblockSet`. According to your definition, `Pdb` is a set of tuples, so it does not have a `pitblockSet` property. You need a concrete tuple to be able to reference the `pitblockSet` property.

In case you want this constraint for each path, this is the way to write it

```
forall (p in Pdb) {
  forall(i in p.pitblockSet , d in DumpBlocks, t in TimePeriods ) {
    sum(j in BlockBelow[i] ) Xbdt[j.id][d][t] == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you again Daniel, Your and Alex's answers have been very helpful to me. As I did not have a formal training in OPL my knowledge of OPL is limited, may be at some stage I will find more on a OPL training.